# input in creating a simple calculator in flash as2

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, flash-cs5

I'm trying to create a simple calculator in Flash using AS2.0. But my input boxes are not accepting numbers,only letter. and my result box (result_txt.text) is displaying a letter "a" whenever I click my operation buttons. Here's the only codes I used:

```
on(release)
{
num1_txt.text = input1_txt.text;
num2_txt.text = input2_txt.text;

var firstNumber = num1_txt.text;
var secondNumber = num2_txt.text;

oper_txt.text = "+";
var resultNumber = 0;
resultNumber = Number(firstNumber) + Number (secondNumber);
result_txt.text = Number(resultNumber);
}
```

I just change the operation symbol for the other operation buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to embed your fonts as I have you can see int the picture . just make sure you have checked all checkbox  in the embed window

[image]

Comment: the behavior of my input text boxes are Single line. What I don't really understand is why my result box (result_txt.text) is displaying a letter "a" whenever I click my operation buttons

Comment: Here's what appears: (image attached) ![Valid XHTML](https://s.yimg.com/hd/answers/i/59381120718e45a6b6065e875e24b991_A.jpeg?a=answers&mr=0&x=1409557826&s=a1d6cb36c754f81951de1e786dde8fa9)

Comment: would you mind uploading your file somewhere then I can see whats the problem?

Comment: uploaded it at https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l3xvg78n8a08gvq/AACfuIb3U02mCQbng93Erzqpa?dl=0 let me know if you can access it

Comment: Yes I downloaded it and as I said the problem is just embeding fonts I'll change the answer. see it